# Git cherry pick diff between two commits, then result commit into another branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-cherry-pick

How can I cherry pick diff in branch A between commit 111 and 222, then result should be committed into branch B using git.

I have software release 
v1.0 (commit 111) + my custom changes (commit 222). 
I also have a release v2.0.

Now I would like to cherry pick changes between commit 111 and 222, and commit my custom changes over release v2.0.

How can I achieve this using git?